# Very weird array declaration issue - C

Tags: c, arrays, process

I call this function using "funcName 4"

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int numPassedIn = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d", numPassedIn);
    pid_t kidPID[numPassedIn];
```

The print statement prints "4". Makes sense.

The array kidPID, however, is not initialized (declared?) properly. There is no space for pid_t's to be stored.

If I alter the code to read

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int numPassedIn = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d", numPassedIn);
    pid_t kidPID[4];
```

it does provide space. What's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you think that `kidPID` isn't allocated properly? with static or dynamic size, the array will have the same properties. What's the problem you're having with the first version that you don't have with the second version? (except if you pass no arguments!!)

Comment: Variable length arrays are an optional implementation, so might not be supported by your compiler.

Comment: How do you know it isn't allocated properly?

Answer (score 2):

C allows to declare Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) when the number of elements in an array is determined at run-time.

Thus in this declaration

```
pid_t kidPID[numPassedIn];
```

there is declared a variable length array with the number of elements equal to the value stored in the variable `numPassedIn`. If the value of the variable `numPassedIn` is equal to 4 then this declaration in fact (with some restrictions) is equivalent to the declaration

```
pid_t kidPID[4];
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are now supported only for backward compatibility.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Was a new C Standard Draft published?

Comment: AFAIK that is C11. Optional. In C99 they were the best thing ever. Apparently no more.

Comment: @WeatherVane Optional does not mean backward compatibility does it?

Comment: I struggle to understand why a standard feature should be optional. There must be some politics in there too. Why does it not say "implementation defined"?

Comment: There must be a reason why VLAs were relegated to optional. Perhaps coders should stop promoting them, since they seem to have moved from *ding* to *dong*. Obviously, you will all hate that.

Comment: @WeatherVane Implementation defined means how the feature is implemented. Optional means that a compiler may not implement the feature. It does not ,mean that the feature is backward compatible.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Implementation defined" has a specific meaning in C standards. I don't know how saying "VLAs are implementation-defined" makes any sense. As Vlad said, "optional" doesn't mean backward compatibility -- it just means a (C11) implementation need not provide it provided it defines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`. However, a C99 implementation must provide VLAs. I don't recall VLAs were being said as the "best thing ever" in C99 -- it's just one of many new features introduced in C99.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Roumors are some commercial compiler vendors have objected, with some company from Redmond being a major suspective. Indeed that was a 180degree turn from the normal attitude of the committee which preserved compatibilit up to being ridiculous. As they were not optional in C99 and any modern C compiler also supports this version, they should also support it in C11 mode, so I'd say they can and should still be used and recommended.

Comment: @P.P. please explain what is meant by "standard". I cannot get my brain around "optional standard".

Comment: @Olaf so my guess about politics is correct? And I suppose you realise I am playing devil's advocate?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I can neither confirm nor deny, as I was never nor am I in the committee. But that whole thing has a bad haut-gout imo. (btw: I'm confident the devil has enough advocates available:-). As long there are good compilers which do support VLAs (and FAMs, btw), I just don't feel like not using and recommending them. Much like some extensions of gcc which are way too useful to ignore them.